# Replace Umlauts and specialial characters in Zapier using Javascript

Tags: javascript, replace, zapier

first of all it's my first time using JavaScript so I appreciate every help I can get.
The question i thought is rather simple:

How do I replace the special characters from a String / Object in Zapier?

So for example if the field `lastname = Müller` it needs to be changed to Mueller.

Basically:

```
ä = ae
ö = oe
ü = ue
ß = ss
```

That are the most common ones. Every Javascript Solution i found does not work very well with Zapier besides this one:

```
const nameFix = inputData.nameFix.replace(/ö/g, 'oe');

return {result: nameFix};
```

But here I can only put one Umlaut and I don't know how to add more. (nameFix is the name of the variable.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

thank you guys i found a python code that got it working:

```
line = input_data['nametoFix']

spcial_char_map = {ord('ä'):'ae',ord('ü'):'ue',ord('ö'):'oe',ord('ß'):'ss'} 
print(line.translate(spcial_char_map)) 

output = [{'nameFix': line.translate(spcial_char_map)}]
```